# Why is so obvious that an element of a group is the product of finitely many generators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A colleague said to me that it is by definition of a group. Thinking about that is giving it more sense; but, does anyone have a clarifying explanation?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Finitely generated with respect to what?

Comment: If $G$ is the group, $X \subseteq G$ is the set of generators of $G$. $X$ can be infinite, but $\forall g \in G \;  \exists x_1,\dots x_n$ in $X$ that generate $g$.

Comment: How do you define a "*set of generators*"?  Surely... the property you mention must be very closely related to the definition of a set of generators if it is not *exactly* the very definition of a set of generators of a group (*note, related to the definition of a set of generators of a group, not directly related to the definition of a group itself as you say your colleague claimed*)

Comment: That's just the definition of what it means to be a set of generators. There is nothing mysterious going on.

Comment: I can ask the question in another way:"can there be an element of a group that is product of infinite other elements?"

Comment: That's not really the same question. On the one hand, it is true that if $X$ is a set of generators for a group $G$, then every element of $G$ is a product of (finitely many) elements from $X$ or their inverses. Depending on your definitions, this is either trivial or easy to show. On the other hand, one can have elements that are "infinite products" of other elements (but this requires an understanding of how to define infinite products in your group). For example, in $(\mathbb{R},+)$, $1$ is the product of $1/2$, $1/4$, $1/8$, $1/16$, ....

Comment: The product on a group is a binary operation: input an ordered pair of elements $g_1,g_2$, output their product $g_1g_2$. The associative law allows us to extend this in a well-defined manner to an $n$-ary operation: input an $n$-tuple of elements $g_1,g_2,...,g_n$, output their product $g_1g_2...g_n$ by inserting parentheses as you please to obtain nested binary operations. **Nothing** allows us to extend this in a well-defined manner to an infinite tuple of elements.

Comment: @halrankard2, it is wilfully misleading to use the term _product_ in the context of $(\Bbb R,+)$!

Comment: @TonyK I  used "product" consistently to mean "the group operation", which here is $+$. (Ok, I admit it was slightly willful. My apologies I must have been ornery a few hours ago.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group), emphasis mine:

> In abstract algebra, a generating set of a group is a subset of the group set such that every element of the group can be expressed as a combination (under the group operation) of **finitely** many elements of the subset and their inverses.

So every element is, *by definition*, the product of only finitely many elements of the generating set.

On the other hand, the comments ask: "can there be an element of a group that is product of infinite other elements?" This is a more interesting question, and related to the idea of the "boundary" of, for example, [hyperbolic groups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov_boundary). Anyway, here is a concrete example of an element of $\mathbb{R}$ under addition, which is an "infinite product". Note that all the elements of the product are contained in the rational numbers while the infinite product is not:

$$e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=1+1+\frac12+\frac16+\cdots$$

Therefore, infinite products can "break out" from the group the individual elements are in.

Remember that we spend a lot of our university education understanding infinite series, like the above. And therefore you should realise that infinite products may not always exist, and if they do then there are subtleties to consider (your product would have to "converge", in a similar way to the above infinite series).